# Category selection for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk

We are going to visit Manchester City football club to see their stadium in detail. We received an invitation from Manchester City for this.

What category do we need to choose? Business and sports or visitor visa?

Comment: Is this an official invitation from MCFC or just the usual tourist tour available for everyone to book? Sounds like the latter to me, in which case it’s a visitor visa. Possibly in itself not a very strong premise for a visit

Comment: The UK no longer has separate business and tourist visas; both kinds of visit now require the [standard visitor visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-visitor-visas).  There may be different ones for sports program exchanges, but your visit doesn't sound like it qualifies as that.

Comment: @MadHatter Post as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

The UK no longer has separate business and tourist visas.  A number of activities are now permissible under the [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa), including

> for leisure, for example on holiday or to see your family and friends
>
> for business, or to take part in sports or creative events

So whether your visit involves taking part in sports or just seeing the sights (in this case, a football stadium), that is the visa you will likely need to apply for.